# Akka Round Robin Pool

Tags: java, akka

I am fetching 40 million rows (data rows) from database table or flat file. I am processing each row for groovy 
evaluation by creating one worker per row (so in this case i am creating 40 million worker).
Here I am using round robin pool of AKKA. Is this approach correct ?? If not what is the best way to do it.

```
public class AkkaWay {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("************************** start *****************************");
    new AkkaWay().run();
    System.out.println("************************** END *****************************");
}

private void run() {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("CalcSystem");
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Master.createMaster(), "master");
    master.tell(new Calculate(), ActorRef.noSender());
    while(!master.isTerminated()){
    try{
     //System.out.println("*********************************** Thread *************************************************");
     Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
}

public class Master extends UntypedActor 
{
private final Time time = new Time();

public Master() {
    workerRouter = this.getContext().actorOf(Worker.createWorker().withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(4)),"workerRouter");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Calculate) {
        time.start();
        processMessages();
    } else if (message instanceof Result) {
        list.add(((Result) message).getFactorial());
        if (list.size() == messages)
            end();
    } else {
        unhandled(message);
    }
}

private void processMessages() 
{
    //read data from file/database (40 millions rows )
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        workerRouter.tell(new Work(), getSelf());// each row send
    }
}

private void end() {
    time.end();
    System.out.println("Done: " + time.elapsedTimeMilliseconds()+"["+time.elapsedTimeMilliseconds()/1000+" secs]");
    getContext().system().shutdown();
}

public static Props createMaster() {
    return Props.create(Master.class, new ArraySeq<Object>(0));
}
}

public class Worker extends UntypedActor 
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Work) {
        //evaluate Groovy expression
        getSender().tell(new Result(bigInt), getSelf());
    } else
        unhandled(message);
}

public static Props createWorker() {
    return Props.create(Worker.class, new ArraySeq<Object>(0));
}
}
```

Comment: codereview seems to be a better fit for this question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the best approach, as in the worst case in might lead you to have 40 mio rows loaded in memory, waiting in Actors mailboxes.

This kind of problem is better solved using akka-stream, where only the needed data is loaded at a time.